# Shape Key interpolation

Tags: python, shape-keys

I'm trying to change Shape Key keyframe interpolation from Python. It is possible in *Dope Sheet*'s *Shape Key Editor*, but can't find a way to change it from Python. I can't even access shape keys. I'm using `bpy.types.Mesh.shape_keys` which I copied from API documentation but it gives me the error "*Mesh doesn't have shape_keys*".

I just have a button that changes interpolation for shape key fcurves to constant. This is the code I arrived at but I'm not getting anything from this:

```
def execute(self, context): 
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
        if obj.type == 'MESH': 
            shape_keys = bpy.types.Key 
            if shape_keys is not None: 
                for key_block in shape_keys: 
                     if key_block.relative_key is None:
                         key_block.interpolation = 'KEY_CONSTANT' 
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Can anyone help me with that? How can I change interpolation for shape_keys? Is it even possible?

Comment: A little demo example of what you are trying to do (test setup + code) would help to answer your question.

Comment: That's all I'm trying really, just have a button that changes interpolation for shape key fcurves to constant. This is the code I arrived at but I'm not getting anything from this:

    def execute(self, context):
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                shape_keys = bpy.types.Key
                if shape_keys is not None:
                    for key_block in shape_keys:
                        if key_block.relative_key is None:
                            key_block.interpolation = 'KEY_CONSTANT'
        return {'FINISHED'}

Comment: Hi! Feel free to edit your question & add the details. I've done this for your last comment. I need to have a closer look at the Graph Editor. But for now, I can tell you that `bpy.types.*` is not what you want. That's the class definitions. The data is in `bpy.data.*`. I've added a shape key to the default cube. They are saved in `bpy.data.shape_keys['Key'].key_blocks` and assigned to the cube by `bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data.shape_keys.key_blocks`. The key_blocks have an `interpolation` property, e.g. `KEY_LINEAR`. Not sure what this is but it's *not* what you see in the Graph Editor :-/

Comment: I'm still not sure if we both mean the same thing, that's why I asked for a screenshot ;-) 
The `key_block.interpolation` is for absolute shape keys only. Uncheck the [X] Relative checkbox to see the Interpolation dropdown menu. --
In the Graph Editor you can change the Interpolation type of key frames, called "Key". That's not a shape key. To access this via Python you have to use the action, for example:  `bpy.data.actions['KeyAction'].fcurves[0].keyframe_points[0].interpolation = 'BEZIER'` See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html#bpy.types.Keyframe.interpolation